# Access logical tree from inside a converter

Tags: wpf

I need to access the Logical Tree inside a converter. Actually this is inside a UserControl, which is (I think) only relevant insofar as this UserControl can live multiple times in my application.

I found a solution, but a rather crude one and my question is: Is there a better, more elegant solution.

Here is what I did. I added an arbitrary control ("Anchor") as a property to my converter. With that control I access the logical tree. In the example I grab the Tag property from the enclosing Grid and convert the value accordingly.

```
public class SomeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public System.Windows.Controls.Control Anchor { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return toUpper() ? value.ToString().ToUpper() : value;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type t, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
    private bool toUpper()
    {
        string tag = (Anchor.Parent as Grid).Tag as string;
        return ! String.IsNullOrEmpty(tag);    
    }
}
```

So far so good. The real ugly part is how I assign the control to the property. I create an empty ContentControl and assign it to the converter definition. In order for the ContontControl to be in the logical tree I also need to instantiate is somewhere, which I do with Visibility=hidden. Here's the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4__Various_Tests_.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4__Various_Tests_"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <ContentControl x:Key="anchor" Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid Tag="toUpper">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:SomeConverter x:Key="SomeConverter" Anchor="{StaticResource anchor}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="anchor" />
    <TextBox
        x:Name="textBox"
        Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}"
        />
</Grid>
```

Comment: It's not clear why you are doing this are what you are actually trying to achieve. Why do you need the logical tree. Looks like you are overcomplicating everything (whatever you are trying to do).

Comment: That may very well be. I have a  TabControl with TabItems. I want to make the visibility of an element in the TabItem depend on a property in the TabControl. But - and that is the catch - only for the selected item. My idea was to make that distinction in the converter.

Comment: ItemTemplate and triggers. TabItem has a property IsSelected. Less code. Better to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using MultiBinding with IMultiValueConverter. There you can pass the target element using a binding.